# Running ssh tunnel in a loop; bad idea? Port already in use?

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, remote

I set up an ssh tunnel from a server which is physically located where I work (it runs CentOS) to home  (Ubuntu) so I can log in to my work tunnel from home, using a command like this on the work computer:

```
ssh -R 49666:localhost:22 homename@homeIP -N
```

I did the keys, etc. I ssh'd from work to home, and then while remotely in my home computer, ssh'd back to work to test it. It seemed fine, it worked. I could scp files both ways, etc.

When I went home later I found that the tunnel had closed for some reason. I couldn't figure out why. I later asked a co-worker about it, and he said he had the same issue, and uses a script like this running constantly on his work computer:

```
while true
 ssh -R 49666:localhost:22 homename@homeIP -N
 sleep 15
```

He basically has this running in perpituity, in order to re-start a broken tunnel automatically when it breaks.

I tried this as well, did the testing (sshed from work to home while physically at work remotely using my home computer) and it seemed fine again. But again, when I went home, the tunnel didn't work. I looked through auth.log and found these three lines at the same timestamp, which would be about when I was halfway home:

```
Accepted publickey from work IP (I erased the rest for my privacy)
error: bind: Address already in use
error: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 49666
```

It seems it tried to bind my tunnel to port 49666 while something else was using it. Okay, I get why that would fail. So I tried to find what's using port 49666 so I could kill it. But nothing seems to be. I tried netstat, lsof, etc. Nothing is using port 49666. I don't think anything EVER uses port 49666 except the tunnel. Could it be that it made the tunnel when the tunnel already existed? Or if the tunnel already existed, would the tunneling looping script simply do nothing?

Since nothing is using port 49666, I would expect that the tunnel would be re-established automatically when the tunnel script on my work computer goes through the loop again, but it doesn't seem like it is.

Is there a way to resolve this without physically going back to the server at work? Or at least, to resolve it with only one tweak so I don't have to go back regularly?

The server never shuts off, so in theory, the looping script should still be going. But would it terminate itself after it fails to make the tunnnel, perhaps?

Comment: In a bash terminal window.

Comment: Also, I just tried doing it again, after changing nothing whatsoever, and it worked. Perhaps the looping script is still running, but it takes a while to re-establish itself? I don't know.

Comment: Whoops, that was idiotic of me. This is the actual code:
while true
do
  ssh -R 49666:localhost:22 max@(removed my ip) -N
  sleep 15
done

Comment: You can [edit] your post to add that

Comment: I waited overnight to see if the tunnel would close again, and it did. I had shut my local ubuntu computer off overnight to see if it would automatically re-establish the tunnel when I turned it back on. As soon as I turned it on, I had the same error in the auth.log: cannot listen to port 49666, already in use, etc. It comes at the same timestamp when I turned the computer on.  Nothing I can find is actually using that port. Is there a way to kill a process on a port even if I don't know what it is? Perhaps a "kill an ssh tunnel" command I can use which will free the port to re-establish it?

Comment: To be clear, I know I can kill the tunnel on the computer that made it by simply killing the script I posted that makes the tunnel, but I can't seem to remote into it at the moment. I mean to kill the tunnel on the computer that is being tunneled into. Although it doesn't seem there is a tunnel, because I can't ssh to it. But if there was no tunnel, then why would the port already be in use and why isn't the looping script re-making the tunnel? Maybe something else is using that port when I'm not checking. Ultimately I'm not sure what to look for here